# Node js - Batches Odata

Tags: javascript, node.js, odata

I need to call the oData service for the HTTP POST operation. Currently I send them as batches of 1000 by  calling all the batches at a time. But there is a problem ,because of concurrent batches that the table gets locked. So I would want to send using $batch with the change set. But I am not sure how to call the Odata service with Changeset in Node.

**Current Code for the batches.**

```
const parallel = async(headers, input) => {
     let payload = [],
        items = [],
        header ;

    const sendreq = async (headers, request, i) => {
         //sending request
    }


    for (var i = 0, len = input.ITEM.length; i < len; i += 1000) {
        items.push(input.ITEM.slice(i, i + 1000));

    }
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        header.ITEM= items[i];
        payload.push(header)
        header = {}
    }
    let j = 0;
    const batches = Array(Math.ceil(input.ITEM.length / 1000)).fill(Array(1).fill(sendreq))

    for (const batch of batches) {
            await Promise.all(batch.map(f => f(headers, payload, j++)))

    } 
}
```